# Parallel.ForEach taking too much time while merging datatable c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to append one DataTable to another DataTable in Parallel foreach loop. I am using Merge to append datatable. It is taking too much time when i use merge or without merge it completes so fast.

```
ReportService _rs = new ReportService();

DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();

 Parallel.ForEach(brandCode, SICode =>            
  {      

      dtMain.Merge(_rs.myFunctionReturnDataTable(SICode));//this takes too much time

      //_rs.myFunctionReturnDataTable(SICode);this does not take time

  });
```

Comment: Are you locking? Merge is not thread-safe. And have you tried adding the rows to the end of dtMain? At its current state, the code is flawed beyond performance. Or does the actual code look different?

Comment: no i am not locking. I did not get that how to adding rows to end of dtMain give some sample code. and this is actual code.

Comment: `DataTable` methods are not thread-safe. You can't do this.

Comment: When you use TPL, you are doing multi-threading. You have to have some knowledge about how to do that. I recommend you do your task in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx) for Merge, I get the feeling that a computationally intensive diff is happening and that your code is slow because that's taking up all your time. DataTable is thread safe for reading but not for writing, so maybe some "bad" thing is happening as well (which could be making this slow for you). Either way, my advice is to put all the results of myFunctionReturnDataTable into a ConcurrentBag and do the merge later. There might be strategic ways of doing the merge later but I'd benchmark on just doing the merge in a loop over each of the returned DataTables and see how far it's gotten you.

Comment: If Merge is the bottleneck, your approach won't solve anything. A performance issue doesn't get better in a single thread.

Comment: It seemed to me that there are two bottlenecks, one that justifies the parallelization over myFunctionReturnDataTable and the emergent bottleneck from Merge. As I point out, Merge is not thread safe and my suggestion to move it out of the current loop is reasonable to disentangling the two bottlenecks. If the only issue was that Merge is slow then there isn't a high abstraction answer (although there might be reasonable strategies based on the returned DataTables). We know the situation is more complex though since Merge is not thread safe.